# How do I get a backup of CiviCRM working on a different server?

Tags: backups, webserver

If I restore a backup of a site with CiviCRM onto another server it seems that it does not work. Getting it to work is especially troublesome if I restore to a different operating system (Linux -> MacOSX, e.g.), but also differences in server setup seem to be problematic.

Is there a way that always works?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple "gotchas" when relocating a working CiviCRM install. (CiviCRM's wiki page on [Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location) is seven pages printed out!) Here's what we watch out for when moving sites.

**Filesystem paths**

CiviCRM stores filesystem paths in various locations in the DB, which can cause a restored DB to not function when loaded in another location.

The simplest way to work around this is to use the facility to [Override CiviCRM settings in `civicrm.settings.php`](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Override+CiviCRM+Settings) to ensure that all the settings in `$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']` are "locked" to values which work in the new environment.

```
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['uploadDir'] = '/path/to/site/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload';
$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['imageUploadDir'] = '/path/to/site/sites/default/files/civicrm/images';
$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['customFileUploadDir'] = '/path/to/site/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom';
$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir'] = '/path/to/site/sites/default/civicrm/extensions';
$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['customTemplateDir'] = '/path/to/site/sites/default/civicrm/custom_tpl';
```

This prevents the settings being changed via the web interface at `civicrm/admin/setting/path` while the settings are overridden in the settings file.

Sometimes Drupal has a variable `civicrm_class_loader` set with a fixed path - it may help to remove this variable.

```
drush vdel civicrm_class_loader
```

I think that I've seen mention of the hardcoded paths issues being addressed in 4.7 cycle, which would be great news IMO.

**Definer in DB dumps**

This is the most common cause of trouble reloading CiviCRM DB dumps.

The cause is that MySQL's default dump behaviour is to include trigger creator information in the dump - which will upset MySQL if you load the dump on a server where the original MySQL user doesn't exist. This looks like this in a MySQL dump:

```
/*!50017 DEFINER=`civicrmuser`@`localhost` */
```

The solution is *really* simple: use the `--skip-triggers` option when making your MySQL export. MySQL will omit the user-specific information, and CiviCRM will sort the triggers out the next time it rebuilds its caches.

If you've already got a large DB dump and don't want to make/transfer a new one just to remove that information, you can also do it using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/DEFINER=`[^`]+`@`[^`]+`/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER/g' dump.sql > new dump.sql
```

I'm not sure if there are plans to address this?

**Permissions**

CiviCRM runs (in UNIX space) as the webserver/php user, and you probably restored the codebase / site files as your system user. In order to permit CiviCRM to function, you likely need to either change the ownership of the CiviCRM-writeable files to the webserver user (eg `chown -R www-data: /path/to/sites/default/files/civicrm`) OR find some other way to ensure that permissions are managed to ensure your user and the webserver user will not conflict.

There's an existing question on this topic: [CiviCRM does not have permission to write temp files](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/civicrm-does-not-have-permission-to-write-temp-files/2931#2931) which covers the merits of various approaches to dealing with CiviCRM's special requirements when it comes to filesystem perms.

The main cause of this issue is the use of a disk cache for `templates_c`. Moving cached HTML to DB (as per Drupal's `cache_*` tables) or to a permissionless store (Redis, memcache etc) would remove this friction, but I'm not sure if / where that is on the roadmap.

**Other considerations**

You may also -

- need to remove the file `ConfigIDS.ini` from your new site. CiviCRM will regenerate this file.
- need to trigger CiviCRM to revisit its idea of which extensions are installed ("Refresh" @ `civicrm/admin/extensions`)
- need to visit `civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend` to reset CiviCRM's caches and stored paths

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

- take a backup (I use Akeeba, since I'm almost always Joomla-based)
- restore it on the new server (Akeeba kickstart, to your aid)
- fixup all configuration files with the following script:

  ```
  #! /bin/sh                                                                                                                                                               
  #                                                                                                                                                                        
  remotebaseurl=<remote url>
  remotewebroot=/var/www
  remotesqlhost=localhost
  localbaseurl=<local url>
  localwebroot=/Library/Webserver/Documents
  localsqlhost=127.0.0.1
  localsqldb=<sqldb>
  localsqluser=<sqluser>
  localsqlpassword=<sqlpassword>

  # save a backup of configuration files                                                                                                                                   
  backup() {
      cp $1 $1.backup
  }

  backup administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
  backup administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php
  backup administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.tpl
  backup components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php


  # tweak all configuration files                                                                                                                                          
  sed -e "s|$remotebaseurl|$localbaseurl|" -i ".bak"   administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

  sed -e "s|$remotebaseurl|$localbaseurl|" -i ".bak"   components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

  sed -e "s|$remotewebroot/|$localwebroot/|" -i ".bak" administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php
  sed -e "s|$remotewebroot/|$localwebroot/|" -i ".bak" administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
  sed -e "s|$remotewebroot/|$localwebroot/|" -i ".bak" administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.tpl
  sed -e "s|$remotewebroot/|$localwebroot/|" -i ".bak" components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
  sed -e "s|$remotewebroot/|$localwebroot/|" -i ".bak" media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini

  rm -r media/civicrm/templates_c/*

  sed -e "s|mysql://.*\?|mysql://$localsqluser:$localsqlpassword@$localsqlhost/$localsqldb\?|g" -i ".bak"       administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
  sed -e "s|mysql://.*\?|mysql://$localsqluser:$localsqlpassword@$localsqlhost/$localsqldb\?|g" -i ".bak" components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

  echo "DONE!"
  ```

Feel free to copy and modify!